# PDO Get amount of rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script written in PDO, which gets the amount of messages the user has and displays them. My issue is that it's not displaying the amount.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", dbuser, dbpass);
$username = $_GET['username'];
$messages = $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT NULL FROM messages WHERE username=:username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
echo $messages; 
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT NULL` means “select null” aka “select no value”. Your query returns a set of Null values.

Comment: How would I select the number of rows?

Comment: Use `SELECT *` to select all fields, `SELECT username,fieldname1,etc...` to select some fields, `SELECT COUNT(*) AS tot` to select the total rows number.

Comment: [Select the number of rows using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/count)

Answer (score -2):

**use rowCount() function if you want to calculate the no of row return by select statement -**

```
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", dbuser, dbpass);
$username = $_GET['username'];
$messages = $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT field1,field2 FROM messages WHERE username=:username");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$total = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $total; 
?>
```

Comment: Did you even read the manual page entry at php.net about this function? It doesn't even work for a SELECT statement. In case you are wondering where -1 came from - it's because you posted completely wrong answer.

Comment: Yes @ NB I read It. this is the link [PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: NEVER use rowcount to count the number of rows.